# WPF update TextBox when resume the timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I work at a game and i have a small issue. I have a timer in this game and i want to resume when i press resume from other form(personal MessageBox). The textbox starting correctly but when i open that messageBox and i resume, the textbox is not updated with the timer value.

Resuming function

```
public void Resume()
    {
        gameTime.Start();
        if (timeJoc > 0)
        {

            timeJoc--;
            countdownJoc.Text = timeJoc.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Button Function

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        LevelOne ptTimp = new LevelOne();
        ptTimp.Resume();

    }
```

Comment: The code is not inside the timer's tick event,what do u expect ?:(

Comment: @zackraiyan in the windows loaded, i have the timer. here is only start or stop. When i open the new window the textbox is blocked at, by example 30 sec. When i resume, the timer starts but the textbox is not updated... thanks

Comment: u mean `countdownJoc.Text = timeJoc.ToString()` doesn't work ?

Comment: @zackraiyan yeap, i think. but inside the timer tick it works

Comment: and what is `timejoc` ? even if it's an `int` , where do set it's values ?

Comment: isn't it obvious that `timeJoc` is not `>` than 0

Comment: @zackraiyan timejoc is the integer which is counted down with 1 sec timespan.

Comment: no it's not .... it's obvious that the value is 0 or less than 0

Comment: show us the code where u do this : `the integer which is counted down with 1 sec timespan`

Comment: gameTime = new DispatcherTimer();
            gameTime.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            gameTime.Tick += gameTime_Tick;

Comment: where does `timeJoc` get the value from ?

Comment: public void gameTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timeJoc > 0)
            {
                timeJoc--;
                countdownJoc.Text = timeJoc.ToString(); } }

Comment: public int timeJoc=45; which means the the countdown starts from 45 sec

Comment: Could you please update your code with all the relevant pieces so we can see what's going on.  Scattered in comments is not at all clear. As you do so, please consider carefully whether you're posting enough for anyone to follow and diagnose without you then coming back and explaining you missed something else out. Thanks.